# How to fit a gls model with a known slope

Tags: generalized-least-squares, offset

i want to fit a gls model (from nlme package) with a specified slope, so i can get the computed intercept for the best fit. I tried to set the slope with an offset. Althogh it works fine with lm, it seems to get ignored when using gls (which i need to, sence my dataset presents heteroscedasticity).

Here is an example (lets say the known slope is 2.5).

set.seed(6)

x <- runif(100, -3, 3)

y <- 2 + x + rnorm(100)

library(nlme)

lm1<-lm(y ~ offset(x*2.5))

gls1<-gls(y ~ offset(x*2.5))

gls2<-gls(y ~ 1)

coef(lm1);coef(gls1);coef(gls2)

> coef(lm1)
>
> (Intercept) 
>   1.606107
>
> coef(gls1)
>
> (Intercept)
>      2.078286
>
> coef(gls2)
>
> (Intercept) 
>      2.078286

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `gls(y - 2.5*x ~ 1)`

Comment: @whuber It worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The help page for `nlme::gls`  says

> offset terms in model are an error since 3.1-157 (2022-03): previously they were silently ignored.

So just use the comment from user whuber, using an offset is the same as subtracting the offset term from the response. Details at [Why is the plot of residuals against fitted values a horinzontal line when the dependent variable is linearly related to the indenpendent variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100682/why-is-the-plot-of-residuals-against-fitted-values-a-horinzontal-line-when-the-d/100736#100736)